# reverse binary file without structures in c

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles, fseek

I have a binary file of numbers, for example 1234. I need to reverse it **in C** to become 4321 without structures or arrays to help me. I thought of having to file pointers: one to the beggining and one to the end, and swap them until they reach each other.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
FILE* f1;
f1 = fopen("C:\\temp\\file2.bin","r+b");
if (!f1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "file doesn't exist");
    exit(1);
}
reverse(f1);
fclose(f1);
exit(0);
}

void reverse(FILE* fr) {
int i1 = 0, i2 = -2;
char c = '\0', tmp = '\0', size;
FILE* f1 = fr;
fseek(fr, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(fr);
fseek(fr, -1, SEEK_END);
while ((i1 - i2) != size+2) {
    fread(&c,1, 1, fr);
    fseek(f1, i1, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&tmp, 1, 1, f1);
    fwrite(&c,1, 1, f1);
    fwrite(&tmp, 1, 1, fr);
    fseek(fr, i2, SEEK_END);
    i1++;
    i2--;
}
fclose(f1);
}
```

It seems allright and doesn't have any bugs but the file remains the same.

Comment: Th last fseek should be SEEK_SET - not SEEK_END

Comment: If it does not reverse, it seems to have one big bug alright. <g>. But I think @DanByström is right.

Comment: You're talking about   fseek(fr, i2, SEEK_END)?   why? I want to set fr to the next char from the end, and i2 will always be negative so it fits.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I read your code wrong, I thought you initialized i2 to size. My bad.

Comment: What seems to be the problem then?

Comment: ISTM that you see `f1` and `fr` as separate entities, but they point to the same file structure, so using SEEK_END on `fr` is like using it on `f1`, and vice versa, so you are not reading or writing what you think you are.

Comment: Normally, using SEEK_END alright, but you must do the SEEK_SET and SEEK_END before you read, since both apply to the same file.

Comment: IT WORKS!  I added 2 lines inside the while loop just before fwrite, only setting f1 and fr with fseek again with the same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

1- read the file from bottom to top, write the bytes in a temporary file (top to bottom)

2- call unlink() to delete the original file

3- rename() the temporary file as the original

But that's called cheating :p

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It can probably be optimized a bit, by reading from the same place and the succeeding byte, but I did not spend my time to optimize it:

```
void reverse(FILE* fr)
{
    int i1 = 0, i2 = -2;
    char c = '\0', tmp = '\0';
    long size;
    fseek(fr, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fr);
    getch();
    while ((i1 - i2) < size+2)
    {
        fseek(fr, i1, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&c,1, 1, fr);
        fseek(fr, i2, SEEK_END);
        fread(&tmp, 1, 1, fr);
        fseek(fr, i2, SEEK_END);
        fwrite(&c,1, 1, fr);
        fseek(fr, i1, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&tmp, 1, 1, fr);
        i1++;
        i2--;
    }
}
```